# vue-cropperjs при загрузке картинки выводит ошибку no 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' и не выводит canvas

Tags: vue.js, cors

Я использую плагин vue-cropperjs для редактирования изображений. У меня возникает ошибка

`acess to XMLHttpRequest at 'url картинки' from origin 'домен сайта' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

я читала что это означает и как бороться, а именно поставить `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`
в header запроса

но я не понимаю, куда мне это ставить, я собственноручно ничего не отправляю. прошу помощи в понимании как в таком случае работать с CORS и решении ошибки

```js
vue-cropper(
  :src="imageSrc"
).cropper

data () {
    return {
      imageSrc: 'https//:namesite/image.png'
     }
}
```

Comment: Как минимум потому что протокол пишется как `https://`, а не `https//:`. Для картинок обычно CORS не срабатывает, их можно безболезненно тянуть с любого сайта на свой (в этом смысл CORS, чтобы не дать стороннему сайту запустить вредоносный код, картинки условно таковыми не являются).

Comment: @VladimirGonchar ну напутала чутка) когда тут писала, а так у меня правильно написано, ошибка есть

Comment: в общем, тут прикл в том, что сам corpper делает проверку, и ее тут либо отключать, либо на стороне бэка дать разрешение и имено этим я и воспользуюсь

Comment: Какую проверку? Что Вы хотите отключать?) Кроппер ничего такого требовать не должен, он фронтовый и просто получает картинку (ровно как и сам Vue, тут разницы никакой)

Comment: @VladimirGonchar да, я поняла, проблема не в плагине, а в запросе, который посылается на наш сервер